# New rows missing from DataTable upon ColumnChanged

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, datatable

I am displaying a DataGridView to the user. This DataGridView has its DataSource set to a DataTable with an identifier ("ID"), alongside other data. Every time a value in the ID column is changed, I want to iterate over all rows to check whether the ID is truly unique; however, I want to avoid doing it when any other column is changed as quite performance-heavy task are executed for the ID column. Hence, I figured that a good option would be to use the ColumnChanged event, from which I can access which column has been changed, and can reset the value if needed.

This approach works fine for when existing rows are changed in long lists, however, I noticed one major flaw: When I add a new row through the DataGridView, the ColumnChanged event is fired while the row itself is not actually included in the DataTable, so iterating over the DataTable would lack one row, rendering many tasks unable of properly processing the DataTable.

I noticed that once RowChanged is called, the DataTable *does* include the row, but I cannot access which column is changed, which I require as pointed out above. Is there a way to fix this or there a workaround I can use?

To visualize my problem, I made the following example: Every time the ID column is altered, the user will be notified about the change, while the program will check whether there are duplicate IDs and notify the user if there are any. You will find, however, that when you add a new row and the first thing you do in it is changing the ID column to a value that already exists, the user will be notified of the change, but not of the duplicate.

(Note that this example is just an example, the way I actually check the DataTable is far more complex and therefore I require the row to be present in the DataTable at the time the event is called.)

Program.cs (this is the default-generated from Visual Studio):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp2
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Der Haupteinstiegspunkt für die Anwendung.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
}
```

Form1.Designer.cs (standard-generated Form class plus DataGridView):

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp2
{
    partial class Form1
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Erforderliche Designervariable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Verwendete Ressourcen bereinigen.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">True, wenn verwaltete Ressourcen gelöscht werden sollen; andernfalls False.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Vom Windows Form-Designer generierter Code

        /// <summary>
        /// Erforderliche Methode für die Designerunterstützung.
        /// Der Inhalt der Methode darf nicht mit dem Code-Editor geändert werden.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.dataGridView1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dataGridView1)).BeginInit();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // dataGridView1
            // 
            this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
            this.dataGridView1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
            this.dataGridView1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
            this.dataGridView1.Name = "dataGridView1";
            this.dataGridView1.RowTemplate.Height = 24;
            this.dataGridView1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(800, 450);
            this.dataGridView1.TabIndex = 0;
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(8F, 16F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(800, 450);
            this.Controls.Add(this.dataGridView1);
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "Form1";
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dataGridView1)).EndInit();
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView dataGridView1;
    }
}
```

Form1.cs (the important stuff):

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private DataTable dt;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("ID");
            dt.Columns.Add("First Name");
            dt.Columns.Add("Last Name");

            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["ID"] = "1";
            dr["First Name"] = "John";
            dr["Last Name"] = "Smith";
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);

            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

            dt.ColumnChanged += Dt_ColumnChanged;
        }

        private void Dt_ColumnChanged(object sender, DataColumnChangeEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Column.ColumnName == "ID")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("The ID column has been changed, it will now be checked.");

                List<string> names = new List<string>();

                foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                {
                    string id = (string)dr["ID"];

                    if (names.Contains(id))
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("The ID " + id + " is already present.");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        names.Add(id);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try following : Boolean found = dt.AsEnumerable().Any(x => x.Field<string>("ID") == "abcd");

Comment: If I understand correctly, this piece of code checks whether a string is already present and returns it as a boolean. Sadly, this does not quite fit my question, as the respective row does not suddenly appear in the DataTable. The example I provided just serves to visualize the issue, they way I check the DataTable in the actual program is far more complex and requires the entire row to be presented and referencable through the DataTable in multiple files.

Answer (score 0):

> I require the row to be present in the DataTable at the time the event is called

The row in DataGridView can't be  inserted in the DataTable Except it's committed by moving to the next row in DataGridView, so you can't add row to the  DataTable  within this event `Dt_ColumnChanged`.

> Is there a way to fix this or there a workaround I can use?

You can handle the duplicated values in ID column in this way:

1) Remove The event `Dt_ColumnChanged`

2) Set the column ID of the DataTable  unique:

```
     dt.PrimaryKey = new[] { dt.Columns["ID"] };
```

3) handle the `DataError` Event of the DataGridView:

```
            private void dataGridView1_DataError(object sender, DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs e)
            {

                // If the data source raises an exception when a cell value is commited, display an error message.
                if (e.Exception != null && e.Context == DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit)
                {
                    var data = dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].EditedFormattedValue;

                    MessageBox.Show($"The ID {data} is already present.");
                    System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(e.Exception.Message); //log error
                    //The Exception.Message will be e.g.: Column 'ID' is constrained to be unique.  Value 'xx' is already present
                    e.ThrowException = false;

                }
            }
```

So the user can't add /modify duplicated values Of ID column and data in DataGridView / DataTable will be consistent.

**Update**

For the comment:

> where I explicitly check for multiple rows with the same value and assign colors

You can search DataGridView like:

//search the column "First Name" to match a value "john" and set back color

```
            private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {          

                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
                {               
                    row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;
                    if (row?.Cells["First Name"]?.Value?.ToString().Trim() == "john")
                    {                   
                        row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: This makes sense and is probably a good approach, however not all columns I check for certain values are bound to being unique, sometimes quite the opposite (where I explicitly check for multiple rows with the same value and assign colors to separate sheet, etc.)

Comment: I updated my answer to show "how explicitly check for multiple rows with the same value and assign colors"